# AngularをTypeScriptで書いているのですが、サービスをcontrollerに注入して関数を呼び出したいのですがうまくいきません。

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

AngularをTypeScriptで書いているのですが、サービスをcontrollerに注入して関数を呼び出したいのですがうまくいきません。
期待する定義と動作は

○サービスとコントローラclassを分ける。
○DIされたコントローラからサービスに定義されている関数を呼ぶ(ここではadd()です。)
○console.logとして出力されればいいです。

※serviceをmodule内にclassとして入れて2つのmoduleを作りimportし、呼び出すのもできればやりたいことです。(今はservice定義のclass浮いている状態です。)

こちらが出たエラーです。

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]               http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=tabibito&p1=Error%3…    %3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)
```

angular with Tyescript is

```
/// <reference path="../vendor_def/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
  /// <reference path="../vendor_def/jQuery/jquery.d.ts"/>


class fafaService{
constructor(){
}
add(){
     return 'mySrvice!!!!';
}
 }
module tabibitoModule {
export class TabibitoClass{
    service;
    constructor(fafaService)
    {
        this.service = fafaService;
        this.service.add();
    }
}
}


var ii = angular.module('tabibito',['ngRoute']);
ii.service('fafaService', fafaService);
ii.controller('SampleController',['fafaService']);
```

コンパイルされたTSファイルです。

```
/// <reference path="../vendor_def/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../vendor_def/jQuery/jquery.d.ts"/>
    var fafaService = (function () {
    function fafaService() {
    }
    fafaService.prototype.add = function () {
        return 'mySrvice!!!!';
    };
    return fafaService;
})();
var tabibitoModule;
(function (tabibitoModule) {
    var TabibitoClass = (function () {
        function TabibitoClass(fafaService) {
            this.service = fafaService;
            this.service.add();
        }
        return TabibitoClass;
    })();
    tabibitoModule.TabibitoClass = TabibitoClass;
})(tabibitoModule || (tabibitoModule = {}));
            angular.module('tabibito'['ngSanitize','ngOMessageFormat']).service('fafaService',     fafaService).controller('SampleController', ['fafaService']);
```

html側です。いろいろ書いてありますが使っているのはコントローラぐらいです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tabibito">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/jQuery/dist/jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/angular-message-format/angular-message-format.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bower_components/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <link href="./stylesheets/dest/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>tabibito</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SampleController as c">
    <h1>Angular独習 input</h1>
    <h2>ng-swichでセレクトタブからのコンテンツ変更</h2>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="season">
            <option value="">四季を選択</option>
            <option value="spring">春</option>
            <option value="summer">夏</option>
            <option value="autum">秋</option>
            <option value="winter">冬</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-switch="season">
            <span ng-switch-when="spring">春は曙</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="summer">夏は夏</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="autum">秋葉秋</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="winter">冬です</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>配列オブジェクトをループ処理する</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in c.author">
            <th>{{key}}</th><!-- c.keyではない-->
            <th>{{value}}</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I expect return 'myService!!!' by add();

Comment: Is there any reason to post this question in English to **JA** stackoverflow?

Comment: I want to ask  this quetion  to people of world,
Here is a dedicated to Japan?? I misstake.. but it's ok maby

Comment: もし英語で質問されたいのであれば、jaのつかない http://stackoverflow.com/ ですね。ja.stackoverflowに残すのであれば、質問を日本語に書き直していただけると助かります。

Comment: @front-end-engnier  プロフィール等から日本語話者だと思われるので日本語で書きますが、全世界的に尋ねたいという要望でしたら、英語で [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) へ投稿されることをお勧めします。ここでの質問は日本語で書き、[stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) へは同様の質問を英語で書く、という手段は有りだと思います。

Comment: @unarist
ご指摘ありがとうございました。ここに投稿すれば日本語も英語もないとおもっていました。修正させて頂きました。

Comment: @holywise 
ご指摘ありがとうございました。ここに投稿すれば日本語も英語もないとおもっていました。修正させて頂きました。

Answer (score 1):

.tsの最後の行は
`ii.controller('SampleController',['fafaService', tabibitoModule.TabibitoClass]);`
ではないですか？

Comment: 取り急ぎお礼したくてコメントします！！
ありがとうございます！初歩的な箇所で恥ずかしいです。。
ただ目的のserviceを使って、というのはまた違う問題みたいです。。
一旦ありがとうございました！！